# react-navigation how to place tabBarNavigation on top of image background

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to set tabBarNavigation on top of image background so that I can see the image background through the tabBar. If I set the `position` to `absolute` I can see my background image but text and tabBar is missing. This is my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  render(){
  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <AppContainer/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
 }
} 

class HomeScreen extends Component {

  render(){
  return(
      <View>
      <ImageBackground
                style={{width:375, height:400}}
                source={require('./assets/pizza.jpg')}>
                </ImageBackground>
      </View>
  )
}
}

const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home:{
  screen:HomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      tabBarVisible:true,
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    }
  },
  Second:{
  screen: Second,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      tabBarVisible:true,
      }
    },
    Third:{
    screen: Third,
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarVisible:true,
        }
      },
    Fourth:{
    screen: Fourth,
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarVisible:true,
        }
      }
    }, {
    tabBarOptions: {
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'gray',
//If I set position to absolute, I can see background image but text is missing
      position:'absolute'
    }
  }
}
  )

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppTabNavigator)
```

[image]

Any comments or advice would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve could you be more specific to that ? Do you want to see the image as background of your tab bar instead of the grey colour ?

Comment: @SurajMalviya yes thats exactly what I want. Sorry if I was not specific.

Comment: Have you tried keeping your code just like it outputs in the image 1 with image on the back of navigator and setting the navigator's background as `transparent` ? I believe it should work. Moreover, you can also go with the `elevation` property to set -1 for the ImageBackground. Please update here if you succeed that way.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `tabBarOptions: {
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }
  }` this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hoped you want to implement like shown in image : [image]

If so, modify your **tabBarOptions** :

```
  tabBarOptions: {
   showLabel: true,
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom:  Dimensions.get('window').height-tabBarHeight,
        left:0,
        right:0
    },
    labelStyle:{
      fontSize:15,
      color:"black"
    }
  }
```

You can see also at https://snack.expo.io/HkoC8SA0Q.

Comment: wow that worked! thanks. But I don't understand what happen. It would be really nice if you could explain what is going on. I would really appreciate it! :)

Comment: I just played the values of position and bottom, If you set "position: absolute", you can control the location of its. :D. Nothing special!